# Como recibir una Variable Type DateTime desde MYSQL en archivo PHP

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Amigos mi intencion es recibir el valor de un campo **type = datetime** proveniente de MYSQL en una archivo php

```
$sql=mysqli_query($con,"select fecha FROM tabla1 WHERE campo1=1");
  $rw=mysqli_fetch_array($sql);
    $fecha_que_recibo=$rw['fecha'];
```

La fecha que deseo recibir tiene el siguiente formato en la base de datos **Año/Mes/dia/hora/minuto/segundo** Ejemplo: ***2017-08-12  11:38:05***

Aqui les dejo el Error que me arroja el php **date(): It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected the timezone 'UTC' for now, but please set date.timezone to select your timezone**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te esta diciendo que no tienes definida la zona horaria de tu servidor php. Puedes editar el archivo /etc/php/7.0/php.ini, buscar la entrada **date.timezone**, descomentarla y asignarle el valor que necesites (por ej: Europe/Madrid). NO te olvides luego de reiniciar el servidor para que coja los cambios.

Tambien puedes hacer, antes de la llamada al date(), hacer la llamada a la funcion que te indica, la **date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Madrid');**.

Revisa http://php.net/manual/es/function.date-default-timezone-set.php para más información.

Personalmente, te recomiendo la primera opcion.

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo he solucionado el problema de ambas maneras en el servidor y definiendo la zona horaria en el archivo que necesito